# Is it possible to trigger onmouseover event on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

On iPhone 3G, is it possible to fire onmouseover event on safari

Comment: What would it be? You can't "hover" around with the "mouse" (your finger) without it triggering the click or drag events.

Comment: I know it's not possible to hover but is iPhone safari support it. I have read somewhere that it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, the behavior is not the same as on a computer, see [this list](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t015) for what triggers mouseover on the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

This works in WebKit. If iPhone Safari supports the event internally, this may work.

```
// Assuming the element you want to simulate a mouseover event with is "theElement"
var mouseoverEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
mouseoverEvent.initMouseEvent('mouseover');
theElement.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is one of the events the iPhone does *not* support :(

Sources:
http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/07/web-development-for-the-iphone/

Comment: Be sure to jump to the section "Safari on iPhone does not support:" in the article!